How do I set boundaries in a multiple definite integral equation?
I've been trying to solve these types of problems for a while now and still can't figure out how to set boundaries for each integral in a multiple integral equation. One of the questions is as follows:

Compute the integral
$$\iint_{\Omega} (-2x + 4y - 2) \ \text{d}\Omega$$
on the region $\Omega = \left\{ (x,y) \in R^2; 4 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 16 \text{ and } y \ge 0 \text{ and } y \le x \right\}$.

And somehow, the boundaries of each integral to solve this equation are as follows :

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{2}^{4} \left( -2(r \cdot \cos \alpha) + 4 (r \cdot \sin \alpha - 2)\right) \cdot r \ \text{d}r \ \text{d}\alpha$$

I get everything except the part on defining the regions of each integral. Any explanation would be really helpful for me. Thanks.
